# I can't access elements on ESPN Fantasy when using BS4 or Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

sample URL: https://fantasy.espn.com/basketball/team?leagueId=454981630&seasonId=2023&teamId=10

So what I want to do is basically grab the names of players in someone's fantasy team. All the names are located under `class="Table__TBODY"` and each player is listed under `"Table__TR Table__TR--lg Table__odd"`.

I tried using BS4 and the `soup.find_all(class_=(Table__TBODY))` but it kept returning none. (My guess would be the site's javascript messed with bs4).

I then switched over to selenium and ran the following to no avail.

```
# pull player from espn team


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
PATH = "C:\ChromeDrive\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://fantasy.espn.com/basketball/team?leagueId=454981630&seasonId=2023&teamId=10
")
print(driver.title)

search = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'Table__TR Table__TR--lg Table__odd')
print(search)
```

However all I got was an error saying the element didn't exist. What's going on? I know the element exists because I'm looking right at it. At first I thought it was because the league was private and selenium couldn't actually access the site the way I saw it but nope, league is public and viewable to anyone.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain why I can't access the element and how I could improve the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In alternative you could also use `request` only while extracting the information from an api, that also will give you a lot of other information in JSON structure.

##### Example

```
import requests

url = 'https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/fba/seasons/2023/segments/0/leagues/454981630?forTeamId=10&scoringPeriodId=1&view=mRoster'
r = requests.get(url, headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
for e in r.json()['teams'][0]['roster']['entries']:
    print(e['playerPoolEntry']['player']['fullName'])
```

##### Output

```
Luka Doncic
Paul George
Bradley Beal
Chris Paul
CJ McCollum
Malcolm Brogdon
Russell Westbrook
Draymond Green
Wendell Carter Jr.
Jerami Grant
John Wall
Aaron Gordon
Bojan Bogdanovic
```

Comment: Hey! I appreciate the solution and it looks like it works perfectly. How did you find this json? Was it in the network tab?

Comment: Happy to help and exactly, it never hurts to take a look at the network tab, the data is often already available in a corresponding structure and can then be pulled directly without having to bring out the "big guns". So I would recommend search and use api first but in mind of your question to deal with selenium, answer of @Barry the Platipus pointed out exactly the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use selenium, here is one way to get those names (and only names. You will need some additional imports as well:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

[..]
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get(url)

players = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "player-column__athlete")]')))
print([x.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').text for x in players])
```

Result in terminal:

```
['Luka Doncic', 'Bradley Beal', 'Paul George', 'Draymond Green', 'Wendell Carter Jr.', 'Chris Paul', 'Jerami Grant', 'CJ McCollum', 'Malcolm Brogdon', 'Russell Westbrook', 'John Wall', 'Aaron Gordon', 'Bojan Bogdanovic']
```

Comment: So was the problem that my code didn't get selenium enough time to extract the information, or was I grabbing the element incorrectly? I appreciate the answer.